# Can this relationship be modelled in UML?

Tags: uml, aggregation

I have received the following UML diagram for implementation:

[image]

From the problem description I know that

- Every Foo belongs to exactly on Block.
- Every Bar belongs to exactly on Block.
- A Bar can belong to none, one or more Foo's *of the same Block*.

**Is this what the UML diagram expresses and if not, 
how can the described relationship be expressed in UML?**

In other words: the relationship between Foo and Bar can only
exist if both belong to the same Block. I have been told that the
aggregation (diamond) in the diagram ensures that this is true.

<sub>I've asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497305/database-schema-for-an-almost-tree) about the same problem.</sub>

Comment: Could the relationship expressed with a composition instead of an aggregation?

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram is OK. In order to express the requirement that the Foos of a bar must be in the same Block of the Bar, you need what is called a constraint. In UML, constraints are usually formulated in the [Object Constraint Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Constraint_Language) (OCL).

Your constraint may be written like this:

```
context Bar
inv: self.foo -> forAll(t |  t.block = self.block)
```

Comment: Is it true then that the aggregation in the diagram has nothing to do with the relationship between Foo and Bar? The OCL requirement is something entirely different and separate from the aggregation?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta1/PDF/ page 194 (in file 204), Figure 11.5

Answer (score 0):

see also http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/tfeng/docs/The%20Unified%20Modeling%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf page 230, Figure 13-70